# Types of RequestCode for startActivityforResult

Tags: android, android-intent

Can anyone kindly list what are the values of `requestCode` to be passed with `startActivityForResult()` and their purpose? Also, can you explain on the `setResult` parameters available like `RESULT_OK` and what else are there? Kindly help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you launch an activity for result with `requestCode >= 0`, this code will be returned to the First Activity's `onActivityResult()` when second activity is finished.You can start multiple `Activity` for result from your `Activity`. In each case you get the callback to `startActivityForResult()` method passing the requestCode. In `onActivityResult()` we can use the requestCode to find out for which activity we have received the callback. So to differentiate between the callbacks from `Activities` we use different requestCodes.

For eg:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 2);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

 if (requestCode == 1) {

  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  //Get the result from SecondActivity
  }

  }
 else  if (requestCode == 2) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  //Get the result from ThirdActivity
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put whatever you want in `requestCode`, it's there for you to know what specific information you are expecting to come back after starting the `Activity` with specified `requestCode`.
The `Activity` which gets called should call `setResult(RESULT_OK)` when it has passed the information to previous `Activity` to verify that this is the right data and everything went fine.

Answer (score 2):

The `requestCode` is up to you. It will help you to recognize which `Activity` has finished, in your `onActivityResult()` method. Also the result parameters are more or less up to you, as long as you're working with your own Activities only. You can think of it as the return value of the called activity to the calling.

Answer (score 2):

The `requestCode` in `startActivityForResult()` is used to allocate an id to request, so that request can be identified with this code, in `onActivityResult()`. Like if someone have written codes to start two activities in an activity B and C, by following Code

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(A.this, B.class), 1);
startActivityForResult(new Intent(A.this, C.class), 2);
```

now in `onActivityResult()` you can recognized which `Activity` has returned result.

The `setResult()` method is used to Set an `Intent` in Result, and a `resultCode`. By `resultCode` we tell `onActivityResult()` that result is ok, or cancelled. in The `Intent` we set in Result, can be used to pass some data, by `intent.putExtra()` methods.